# Trying to send a gmail user 3 copies a singular email using Google App Script. Problem is it is sending them all in a connected thread

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Trying to send a gmail user 3 copies a singular email using Google App Script. Problem is it is sending them all in a connected thread. Very new to programming in general and GAS but found this which sends them all in a connected thread.

```
function send() {
 
  var emailAddress = 'adress';
  var subject = 'subject';
  var message = 'message';
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
    htmlBody: message,
  });
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
    htmlBody: message,
  });
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
    htmlBody: message,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way that Gmail works... it will put in the same thread the emails that have the same subject. If you want to avoid having the three emails in the same thread then your script should assign different subjects.